# Excluding unique ID in a query if at least one criteria is met

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting-services

I'm having this problem which I'm unsure how to resolve.

Here's the situation : I want to get a list of all individuals who have not completed a survey. It is however possible for someone to start/complete multiple surveys.

Therefore, I want the list of individuals who have not completed at least one survey.

Here's what my query looks likes to get the list of people with incomplete surveys :

```
SELECT Survey.UserID, Survey.Fullname

FROM [...]

WHERE Survey.SurveySubmitted = 0    -- 0 = Unsubmitted, 1 = submitted
```

Now this is what the database could look like

```
UserID            Fullname              SurveySubmitted
1                 John Smith            0
2                 Jane Doe              1
3                 Tom Glass             0
3                 Tom Glass             1
```

Now the above query will select both John Smith and Tom Glass. However, since Tom Glass already completed at least one survey, he should be excluded.

Any ideas to proceed? It most likely needs a SELECT within another SELECT but I'm having trouble picturing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for the user not in the user that have submited/completed

```
select Survey.UserID, Survey.Fullname 
from [.....]
where UserID NOT IN (
  SELECT Survey.UserID, Survey.Fullname
    FROM [...]
    WHERE Survey.SurveySubmitted = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should group by whatever uniquely identifies a User/Survey combination and then sum the # of surveys that have been submitted. You can then use a `having` clause to filter out rows > 0:

```
select *
from Survey 
group by UserId, FullName
having sum(SurveySubmitted) = 0;
```

[SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/543088/6)